# How do I best bind query results to an in-memory graph, rather than to a flat collection, with Neo4jClient?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm just starting to dabble in Neo4j and I haven't been able to find a good code sample that implements this simple use case.

I know how to fetch all nodes in an n-level relationship with a given node -- as a flat one-dimensional array or list of objects.

But what is the most elegant way to maintain the graph structure in memory? What's the best way to bind to a simple class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Foo> Relationships { get; set; }
}
```

I can think of all sorts of cheesy hacks such as getting all objects, including relationships, from the db as a flat list -- and then re-creating the in-memory graph "manually" on the client... But please tell me there's a better way.

Comment: Is `Foo` a Node or a Relationship? I'm only asking as I'm trying to see what the `Relationships` property contains - is it a collection of Nodes related to this current node? Is your graph likely to have circular references?

Comment: Foo is a node. The graph will never have circular refs. The Relationships property is a collection of Nodes -- this is just a simple example. :)